# How get all ways without ND tags in Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have this query,

```
area["name"="Greater London"];
way(area)["amenity"="restaurant"]->.all;
( .all; - ._; );
(._;);
out geom;
```

which return me this result

```xml
<way id="4270351">
    <bounds minlat="51.6322589" minlon="-0.0381454" maxlat="51.6327917" maxlon="-0.0376948"/>
    <nd ref="25637026" lat="51.6327251" lon="-0.0379737"/>
    <nd ref="25637027" lat="51.6327917" lon="-0.0377806"/>
    <nd ref="25637029" lat="51.6326585" lon="-0.0376948"/>
    <nd ref="25637030" lat="51.6323298" lon="-0.0378665"/>
    <nd ref="25637032" lat="51.6322589" lon="-0.0380668"/>
    <nd ref="25637034" lat="51.6324054" lon="-0.0381454"/>
    <nd ref="25637026" lat="51.6327251" lon="-0.0379737"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    <tag k="building" v="block"/>
    <tag k="created_by" v="JOSM"/>
</way>
```

Is there a way get same but without ND tags? like this:

```xml
<way id="4270351">
    <bounds minlat="51.6322589" minlon="-0.0381454" maxlat="51.6327917" maxlon="-0.0376948"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="restaurant"/>
    <tag k="building" v="block"/>
    <tag k="created_by" v="JOSM"/>
</way>
```

I will get needed lat lon from , and in this case i don't want to get ND's because this tags make returned data heavy

Comment: Duplicate of https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/61819/how-get-all-ways-without-nd-tags

Comment: Hey @mmd, this is not duplicate. This is my own question in Osm help group. I dont have final answer there. Please check answers before marking as fuplicatr

Comment: You posted the exact same question on 2 different sites without clearly stating so. That’s a waste of everyone’s time.

Comment: I cant understand your angle of view... ìf question dont have answer, what should i do???? Change the question? Or trying find answer in other resurses??     ok, no problem, dont answer and lost your time. Thanks

Comment: Edit both questions and add links to the other sites where you posted your question. Did you check the documentation already as recommended? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Print_.28out.29

Comment: Yes, of course, but there no any way to have results without <nd> tags... Only with type csv, but this solution is not good for my situation. I need xml format but without included ND tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs I mentioned you need to use `out tags;` to omit node details for your ways.

To also include the bounding box, use:

```
way(4270351);out tags bb;
```

Comment: WoW. This is working, this is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot for your BIGGEST help. I will update the OSM help center task also, and wrot your answer.